# naming and configuring jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

This is going to sound like a really stupid question to whoever knows the answer!

When I create a JSfiddle it appears on my listing page like this

`cGzCe Revision 8`

Then I title it 'Multi-create nodes ' (extra space since the revision number is added with no space to this phrase) and update again and get this

`cGzCe Multi-create nodes Revision 9`

I want to alter the text of the cGzCe in the larger font - where can I do that? I forked someone else's fiddle the other day and it had this done, but I couldn't see how the settings differed from one of my fiddles! Help please :-D

...

Also, for a bonus point - does anyone know how to disable the auto-indenting... (or make it work reliably, or lower the indent to two spaces..)

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be willing to reevaluate your accepted answer? The highest up-voted answer seems far better than mine, and probably should be accepted instead. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think this is off-topic for Stack Overflow (and have voted to close as such), the way to have no string of random characters besides the title of the saved Fiddle is, when you *start* the Fiddle, declare its title; if the title is added *after* a point at which it's been previously saved then the string of characters will appear, since that's the 'base'/'original' Fiddle, whereas the 'titled' Fiddle is a later revision.

Comment: that's great thanks. i know what you mean about off topic, but i figure plenty of people here know/want to know. what do you think is the next most appropriate stackexchange board for stuff like this?

Comment: Honestly, I'm really not sure. It could be argued that SO is appropriate, due to the programming-relevance of JS Fiddle; but it seems to be relatively debatable either way.

Comment: One thing more. If you created the fiddle being logged in you can redeclare the base and set the title

Comment: as far as I know, it's valid to ask about programming tools, even ones that are online.

Comment: Grateful that this didn't get deleted as off-topic. It was totally on point for me.

Answer (score 22):

I had trouble replacing the fiddle code number with a fiddle name and description.

Here's how I got the results I wanted:

1. Clicked on "Base" to get the fiddle URL to show as `/xxxxxx/#Base` where `xxxxxx` is the fiddle code.
2. Used the Fiddle Options to set the Fiddle Name as "MyFiddleName" and Description
3. Clicked "Update"
4. Clicked "Set as base"
5. Now the dashboard shows "MyFiddleName" with the description and doesn't show the `xxxxxx` code.

Comment: This is beautiful man, used jsfiddle for years and didn't know how to make the damn things.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what worked for me,

***for new fiddle:***

1. In the left panel, under **Fiddle Meta**, give a name in the "untitled fiddle" input box
2. Click **save** from the top menu to save the fiddle and the given name

***for existing fiddle with code name:***

1. Click on the fiddle to open it.
2. In the left panel, under **Fiddle Meta**, give a name in the "untitled fiddle" input box
3. Click **update** and then **set as base** from the top menu to save the  given name