# How to give a human-readable name to a jsfiddle.net code snippet?

Tags: jsfiddle

Is there a way in jsfiddle.net to give a human-readable name to a code
snippet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under *Fiddle Options* in the sidebar, you can set a name for your fiddle.

[image]

Comment: Does not work, say you are at fiddle version 10, and you name it then you have to update it which takes you to version 11. However, the name that will appear in your dashboard will still be version 1 name which is like 43jIl9KL/???

Comment: This has nothing to do with this answer?

Comment: it has, i did what you said: put the name there, but in dashboard it stills shows up as random numbers.

Comment: It's not supposed to. If you have an account, the name you choose will be displayed, instead of the random hash, in your dashboard.

Comment: ok so look i am at version 9, i found that out you can actually name it. I name it and update it. so now im at version 10. i click at dashboard and still shows up as random numbers of first fiddle but to access last fiddle i gotta click the tiny versions number next to the name of first fiddle. (just to make sure you have to update to apply new name right?) I found a way thats to set it as base it's at top center of screen. However it discards all other versions.

Comment: I am not an expert or developer with the inner-workings of this tool. You can [tweet](https://twitter.com/jsfiddle) them or contact  [Piotr](http://webdev.zalewa.info/contact/) if you are having problems with the software.

Answer (score 16):

There is no need to fork your fiddle after changing the fiddle name. You can just set it as base using the (Set As Base) option at the top.

1) Change the name using the Fiddle Options.

2) Update the version so it is the latest.

3) Set it as base using the option.

4) In the dashboard you can see that the name you mentioned appears.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar trouble trying to name mine at first as well. I updated but it was still random characters, but when I 'Forked' the editor, then it showed as the correct name.

Comment: Yes, forking the Fiddle seems to be the way to get it to work for me also. Then I just delete the original. Seems kinda clunky but probably a good reason behind it.

Answer (score 0):

If the project is provided a name before the first save, it will show that name in the dashboard.  Otherwise, the fork process is required to rename it.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you don't need to fork it. You can set the version with a name as the base version and that name will be displayed in your Dashboard. Noted here: [naming and configuring jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12279579/naming-and-configuring-jsfiddle)